# Adding Serial ATA driver Windows 7 clean install for Dell Inspiron n5110

Tags: windows-7, sata, ata

I want to try format my Dell notebook with Windows 7 Ultimate. But my ISO pack doesn't have any HDD driver in it. When I come to step 2 for installing Windows 7 the system says "You should have to install driver for HDD" bla bla...

My machine is http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/ServiceTag/2C6QFP1

I also found some solutions here

http://forums.mydigitallife.info/threads/13816-Integrating-SATA-drivers?s=400431708d236aae31eb9c4a730dc1ba&p=204166&viewfull=1#post204166

So, how can I find my Serial ATA drivers `.cab` file(s)?

Is there any different method for this?